# Understanding BSC, BEP-20 and ERC-20 tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, bsc

I would like to ask a few questions.

1. If we have an ERC-20 smart contract deployed on Ethereum and if we want to move it to binance smart chain because of high transaction fee, what is the best move moving the smart contract or simply creating a new BEP-20 smart contract? And why?
2. What are the disadvantages of moving the erc-20 contract to bsc since there are very few differences between the two standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really "move" a contract. Once a contract is deployed, it stays there forever (unless it has implemented `selfdestruct`). So you simply need to deploy the same contract with the same source code again in the new blockchain.

The differences between the blockchains are subtle. Mostly:

1. Different governance / (de)centralization models. Ethereum is fully decentralized, BSC is partially decentralized (dPoS)
2. Different use base. Ethereum has more users probably
3. Different services. In theory, they could have almost exactly the same services, but most projects don't launch their products in multiple blockchains (at least immediately)